# Is it possible to sync two iPhones with different service providers via iCloud?

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud

I have a personal AT&T iPhone and my company gave me a Verizon iPhone.  Both are running IOS 5. How can I get all of my contacts from my AT&T phone to my Verizon iPhone since I am required to carry that one 24/7.  Is there a way to do that through iCloud?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what iCloud (and MobileMe did in the past) does for contacts.

Unless your company phone uses a company supplied directory (in which case just connect your personal phone to the company directory) you can sign up for a free iCloud account and store your contacts on both the devices in the cloud.

You could also sync from iCloud to a computer (PC or Mac) as well to an iPad, but you don't have to and can simply use it to sync the address book contents between the two iPhones.